# How to pass parameters through method in consuming soap service using wslite plugin in grails

Tags: web-services, grails, soap, cxf

Im using grails wslite plugin to consume a soap web-service, im able to call the service method from the body section if the parameters are not specified, im getting results from that service method. but I I try to pass the parameters im getting error as

soap:Client - Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"htp://soapauth/", local:"parameters"). Expected elements are <{}count>,<{}status>

My soap service method like this ,I'm using grails cxf plugin to expose it as a service
 @WebMethod(operationName="getReqMethod", action = "getReqMethod")

```
String getReqMethod(  
    @WebParam( name="count") Integer count, @WebParam(name="status") String status ){ 
    print " in service "+count+" -- "+status
```

}

and the wslite client code in my controller  is as follows.

```
 def index(){
    withSoap(serviceURL: 'http://mysite.com/SoapAuth/services/sampleReq') {
          def response = send(SOAPAction: "getReqMethod") {
               header() {
                   auth {
                      username("wsuser")
                     password("secret")                        
                }                  
            }
            body{
                getReqMethod("xmlns": 'htp://soapauth/')
                {
                    parameters{
                        count(2)
                        status("active")
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
        println "res "+response.getReqMethodResponse.text()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be just this instead of `parameters` closure?

```
getReqMethod("xmlns": 'http://soapauth/') {
    count(2)
    status("active")
}
```

Comment: I tried  that also its throwing error as                         soap:Client - Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://soapauth/", local:"count"). Expected elements are <{}count>,<{}status> . Stacktrace follows: